# Does mobile chrome browser cache shared url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching

I am facing a issue with my website on mobile chrome browser. if say www.mysite.com/contact url is shared via whatsapp the next time when i try to share www.mysite.com/home but clicking the whatsapp option by default www.mysite.com/contact comes up.

what is causing it?

I tried clearing chrome browsing history everything but sharing a page always shows the www.mysite.com/contact link.

I see the following coes on the htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(css|x?html?|php)$">  
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
 RewriteRule .* index.php [F,L]
</IfModule>
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

does this has anything to do with my issue?

Comment: It looks like you mean the scraping open graph information. Yes, most platforms cache them.

Comment: please check my edited post i shared my htacess file

Comment: I think, it won't technically change anything and it is not what is affected by your .htaccess caching. Facebook for instance has a [scraper](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) where you can force to refresh. Since Whatsapp is a service from Facebook, I won't wonder about the same behavior.

Comment: i do not see this happening with other websites but only with mine.

Comment: Then try commenting out everything possible.

Comment: Oh i got it. the chronical url was wrong :)